# How to move between tableviews displaying the information of the previous tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, action

I have two view controllers, each of which have a UITableView in them (the view controllers are NOT Table View Controllers... they are normal view controllers with table views in them). In the first tableView I have an array of strings that it displays (successfully). The goal is that when the user clicks on a row, I want it to take them to the next view controller (that has a tableView in it) and display the sub-details of the category that they selected in the previous tableView (For example: In the first view controller tableView the user has a choice between areas of a car [Front, left, rear, etc...] and the user selects "Front"... it should take them to the next view controller and on the tableView display the parts of the car that are located on the "Front"... such as bumper, hood, grille... etc.). In the second view controller I have an array of arrays containing the details of the different categories in the previous tableView.

I need to know what to do when the user selects a row in the first tableView and how to make it display the details on the next tableView. I know it's supposed to someone utilize didSelectRowAt indexPath... I believe?

I'm new to programming, so please make it understandable for a beginner and even explain your answer so that I can learn in the process please. I've spent hours researching and trying to figure this out, but since I don't know much code it's hard to tell what would and wouldn't work for exactly what I'm trying to do.

Thanks

Comment: Can you add what code you have written so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I would start here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH2-SW1 . If you have a specific problem, please ask a new question. See also [ask].